# Single Instance from multiple broadcasts

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I am developing a simple library project which have a broadcast for Battery stats.

I implemented this simple library project in 3 of the my projects. As the result of this, suppose at 30% battery I need to send something to the server, I received the broadcast and send data to server. What is happening is as I have implemented the same broadcast in 3 of my applications, I receives 3 same files at the server.

I need to restrict this, such that only one time the file will be send to the server, that means if from 3 projects if any one received the broadcast other two will not receive it or don't perform the broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

As there are 3 separate broadcast senders so i think the only way to stop this behaviour is make a shared object that the first sender (or receiver) will create with some sort of timestamp and the other will check and if the object is present - stop sending anything to server.
That can be achieved with:
world readable/writable preference (i think it marked as deprecated since api 17..)
or 
some sort of file on sdcard

Comment: I thought of this to putting a shared preference in non private mode and shared that among these receivers, but it not seems fusible logically, as all 3 broadcast will happen at same time so there might occur the same problem as we have with  variable used in multithread type environment. Correct me if I am wrong?